# linux ipv4 forwarding limited throughput

Tags: networking, ipv4, forwarding, wireguard

My symptom is that client PCs on my LAN connecting through the WG tunnel to the remote host would max out around 250 Mbps, but it could be anywhere between 150 and 300 Mbps (i.e. lots of variability with lots of time to settle). I run some WireGuard tunnels on a VM, connecting to a Vultr VM. If I run iperf3 involving the same hosts I get the same result.

I've read this one:

https://serverfault.com/questions/777354/huge-performance-penalty-in-gbit-link-with-ip-forwarding-masquerade-through-cl

and the comments but I still haven't resolved the issue.

However, iperf3 between the WG hosts themselves gives upwards of 650 Mbps. CPU does not seem to be a limiting factor, but I'm okay with 650, vs 250. I mainly want to understand the mechanisms at play.

My initial guess is that the IPv4 forwarding performance of AlmaLinux 9.1 seems to be interfering with throughput. In the case with client connections to the remote WG host, the intermediate AL 9.1 server is forwarding and encrypting.

Round trip time is 10 ms between WG hosts, and I understand the Linux receive window is adaptive. I test with 3 iperf3 streams, and changing that doesn't change total throughput.

In the other post, they "achieved" 1 Gbps with UDP but most of the packets were lost so obviously the link doesn't support that throughput. It's the same in my situation and it tops out around 250 Mbps or so as stated. Are there any settings I can work with? I only have forwarding in my sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

I testing just forwarding between subnets using a Linux host, and it was full gigabit...so that theory is blown and explains why I didn't see recent posts about performance.

Here is an example iperf3 output from a client to the remove WG peer:

```
Connecting to host 10.0.33.1, port 5201
[  4] local 192.168.10.50 port 60045 connected to 10.0.33.1 port 5201
[  6] local 192.168.10.50 port 60046 connected to 10.0.33.1 port 5201
[  8] local 192.168.10.50 port 60047 connected to 10.0.33.1 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  10.4 MBytes  86.6 Mbits/sec                  
[  6]   0.00-1.00   sec  9.25 MBytes  77.2 Mbits/sec                  
[  8]   0.00-1.00   sec  5.62 MBytes  47.0 Mbits/sec                  
[SUM]   0.00-1.00   sec  25.2 MBytes   211 Mbits/sec                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.5 Mbits/sec                  
[  6]   1.00-2.00   sec  9.50 MBytes  79.8 Mbits/sec                  
[  8]   1.00-2.00   sec  10.0 MBytes  84.0 Mbits/sec                  
[SUM]   1.00-2.00   sec  30.8 MBytes   258 Mbits/sec                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec  9.62 MBytes  81.0 Mbits/sec                  
[  6]   2.00-3.00   sec  9.50 MBytes  79.9 Mbits/sec                  
[  8]   2.00-3.00   sec  9.25 MBytes  77.8 Mbits/sec                  
[SUM]   2.00-3.00   sec  28.4 MBytes   239 Mbits/sec                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec  9.38 MBytes  78.4 Mbits/sec                  
[  6]   3.00-4.00   sec  10.1 MBytes  84.7 Mbits/sec                  
[  8]   3.00-4.00   sec  10.1 MBytes  84.7 Mbits/sec                  
[SUM]   3.00-4.00   sec  29.6 MBytes   248 Mbits/sec                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec  8.38 MBytes  70.2 Mbits/sec                  
[  6]   4.00-5.00   sec  7.88 MBytes  66.0 Mbits/sec                  
[  8]   4.00-5.00   sec  10.2 MBytes  85.9 Mbits/sec                  
[SUM]   4.00-5.00   sec  26.5 MBytes   222 Mbits/sec                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec  9.75 MBytes  81.9 Mbits/sec                  
[  6]   5.00-6.00   sec  7.12 MBytes  59.8 Mbits/sec                  
[  8]   5.00-6.00   sec  11.0 MBytes  92.4 Mbits/sec                  
[SUM]   5.00-6.00   sec  27.9 MBytes   234 Mbits/sec                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[  4]   6.00-7.01   sec  11.1 MBytes  93.1 Mbits/sec                  
[  6]   6.00-7.01   sec  6.25 MBytes  52.3 Mbits/sec                  
[  8]   6.00-7.01   sec  11.0 MBytes  92.0 Mbits/sec                  
[SUM]   6.00-7.01   sec  28.4 MBytes   237 Mbits/sec                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[  4]   7.01-8.00   sec  10.0 MBytes  84.1 Mbits/sec                  
[  6]   7.01-8.00   sec  6.38 MBytes  53.6 Mbits/sec                  
[  8]   7.01-8.00   sec  8.00 MBytes  67.3 Mbits/sec                  
[SUM]   7.01-8.00   sec  24.4 MBytes   205 Mbits/sec                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[  4]   8.00-9.01   sec  10.8 MBytes  89.8 Mbits/sec                  
[  6]   8.00-9.01   sec  9.25 MBytes  77.3 Mbits/sec                  
[  8]   8.00-9.01   sec  9.38 MBytes  78.3 Mbits/sec                  
[SUM]   8.00-9.01   sec  29.4 MBytes   245 Mbits/sec                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[  4]   9.01-10.00  sec  8.75 MBytes  73.9 Mbits/sec                  
[  6]   9.01-10.00  sec  9.25 MBytes  78.1 Mbits/sec                  
[  8]   9.01-10.00  sec  8.00 MBytes  67.5 Mbits/sec                  
[SUM]   9.01-10.00  sec  26.0 MBytes   219 Mbits/sec                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  99.4 MBytes  83.4 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  99.2 MBytes  83.2 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[  6]   0.00-10.00  sec  84.5 MBytes  70.9 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  6]   0.00-10.00  sec  84.4 MBytes  70.8 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[  8]   0.00-10.00  sec  92.6 MBytes  77.7 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  8]   0.00-10.00  sec  92.5 MBytes  77.6 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[SUM]   0.00-10.00  sec   276 MBytes   232 Mbits/sec                  sender
[SUM]   0.00-10.00  sec   276 MBytes   232 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

Comment: How many CPU cores does the VM have available?

Comment: It has 8 cores, host CPU so CPU is passthrough

Comment: If you have 1Gbps udp but most packets are lost, then you probably do not actually have 1Gbps. Packets are often lost when a router has been sent too many packets to be able to forward them all, or when its own speed is too slow. 1Gbps to the router does not mean 1Gbps to the internet.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b yes, the UDP just shoves packets down the link. However, I can grab Linux ISOs at 110 MB/s or 940 Mbps, so available throughput isn't an issue. In my specific case, the two WG endpoints are the same, but one between WG hosts gets about 650 Mbps (which I'd be okay with) but an external client forwarding through this host peaks around 300 Mbps, which is what I would like to identify and resolve.